# "Jubiläum" ein Begriff mit positiver Konnotation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ist "Jubiläum" ein Begriff mit positiver Konnotation? Könnte man z.B. von einem Jubiläum eines Todestages, oder gar einer Katastrophe reden?

Comment: Todestag ist ja schon eine Wiederkehr des Tages, an dem der Betroffene verstorben ist. Eine Kombination mit *Jubiläum* ist sinnlos.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Schnelle Antwort:

Da im "Jubiläum" der "Jubel" mit eindeutig positiver Konnotation steckt, würde ich besser *nicht* vom Jubiläum eines traurigen/negativen Ereignisses reden, sondern vom **Jahrestag**, der ist nämlich neutral.

---

Ausführliche Antwort:

In der ursprünglichen Bedeutung aus dem Yiddischen war ein Yovel ein alle 50 Jahre wiederkehrendes Jahr mit besonderer sozio-kultureller Bedeutung (die Details spielen hier keine Rolle, [hier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubilee_%28biblical%29) und [hier](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubeljahr) und [hier (lang...)](http://www.betemunah.org/yovel.html) nachzulesen), im modernen Sprachgebrauch ist die Phrase *alle Jubeljahre* erhalten geblieben.
Über das alle 25 Jahre gefeierte Jubeljahr der römisch-katholischen Kirche (annus jubilaeus) hat sich der Begriff dann von einem längeren Zeitraum auf jährlich wiederkehrende Ereignisse mit "freudigem" Unterton (=jubiläus) übertragen.
-> Damit kann man von einer positiven Konnotation von "Jubiläum" ausgehen.

Answer (score 5):

Zusätzlich zu Stephies ausgezeichneter etymologischer Antwort, eine kleine Quellenschau (zufällige Suchergebnisse von [news.google.de](http://news.google.de)) für Jubiläum:

> - [Jubiläum des vermeintlichen Beweisfotos [des Loch-Ness-Monsters]](http://www.welt.de/vermischtes/kurioses/article139838468/Beruehmtes-Nessie-Beweisfoto-feiert-81-Jubilaeum.html) (Die Welt)
> - [Jubiläum in Siegburg – 200 Künstler zeigen ihre Werke in 25 Jahren Stadtmuseum](http://www.rundschau-online.de/siegburg/jubilaeum-in-siegburg-200-kuenstler-zeigten-ihre-werke-in-25-jahren-im-stadtmuseum,28692138,30479092.html) (Kölnische Rundschau)
> - [Pater hält Andacht zum Kapellen-Jubiläum](http://www.rp-online.de/nrw/staedte/korschenbroich/pater-haelt-andacht-zum-kapellen-jubilaeum-aid-1.5031045) (Rheinische Post)
> - [Klassik am Odeonsplatz: 20 Prozent Jubiläumsrabatt](http://www.abendzeitung-muenchen.de/inhalt.zum-jubilaeum-klassik-am-odeonsplatz-20-prozent-jubilaeumsrabatt.7167b654-c834-4944-b8af-501d83fea752.html) (Münchner Abendzeitung)

Und für Jahrestag:

> - [100. Jahrestag des Massakers: Türkei kondoliert Armenien](http://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/tuerkei-armenier-101.html) (Tagesschau.de)
> - [70. Jahrestag des Kriegsendes – Wer nicht feiert, hat verloren](http://www.berliner-zeitung.de/meinung/70--jahrestag-des-kriegsendes--wer-nicht-feiert--hat-verloren--i-,10808020,30478456.html) (Berliner Zeitung)
> - [Ausschreitungen zum Jahrestag des Fährunglücks in Südkorea](http://de.euronews.com/2015/04/19/ausschreitungen-zum-jahrestag-des-faehrungluecks-in-suedkorea/) (Euronews)
> - [Konzert zum Jahrestag [der Gründung des Orchesters]](http://www.schwarzwaelder-bote.de/inhalt.villingen-schwenningen-konzert-zum-jahrestag.f5843cba-bef7-4d2d-93a1-082eba17b18a.html) (Schwarzwälder Bote)
> - [Kambodscha: Gedenken an Rote-Khmer-Opfer am Jahrestag der Machtübrenahme](http://www.nzz.ch/newsticker/gedenken-an-rote-khmer-opfer-am-jahrestag-der-machtuebernahme-1.18524361) (Neue Zürcher Zeitung)

Man erkennt, wie das *Jubiläum* wirklich nur mit durchgehend positiver Konnotation verwendet wurde. Selbst bei 70 Jahren Kriegsende fällt es schwer, von einem *Jubiläum* zu sprechen – die Berliner Zeitung spricht lieber vom *Jahrestag*. Ähnliches für die Jahrestage des Massakers in Armenien, des Fährunglücks oder (was zwar weiter zurückliegt, mir aber prägnant in Erinnerung ist) des Fukushima-Unglücks.

Der *Jahrestag* kann aber auch für positive Ereignisse verwendet werden; siehe den Jahrestag der Orchestergründung im Schwarzwälder Boten.